# Spring MVC + JSP: Dynamic objects and el variable expressions

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I would like to show a page with all products and their discounts.
The productService gives me all the products, returning a DTO(no discounts or any links to it included)
The discountService brings me the discounts for each product, and add these to the modelAndView with a dynamic name.

```
@RequestMapping("/all")
public ModelAndView getAll(){
    List<ProductDTO> products = productService.findAll();
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("products/all", "products", products);
    for(ProductDTO productDTO : products){
        List<DiscountDTO> discountDTOs = discountService.findAllDiscountsForProductApplicableForUser(productDTO.getId(), userService.getCurrentLoggedInUser());
        modelAndView.addObject("product" + productDTO.getId() + "_applicableDiscounts", discountDTOs);
    }
    return modelAndView;
}
```

I can't seem to find how I can acces these in my JSP page, using EL
${product5_applicableDiscounts} works perfectly, ${'product'+product.id+'_applicableDiscounts'} gets evaluated as a String.

Anyone knwos how to do this?

Comment: Any special reason to show that info in a unique string? maybe you could solve using  Map

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
${requestScope['product'+product.id+'_applicableDiscounts']}
```

But I find it ugly.

Why not add the discounts to the ProductDTO instead? Or create a new class containing a ProductDTO instance and its applicable discounts, as bean properties?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use spring's eval tag

```
<spring:eval expression="product${product.id}_applicableDiscounts" var="discounts"/>
```

and then you can use the "discounts" variable.